# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'event' of undefined using Laravel 5.3

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I am new to laravel. This my script code. I am using this script to retrieve Location in my input field.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">


        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {
        var places = new    google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('job_location'));
        google.maps.event.addListener(places, 'place_changed', function () {
            var place = places.getPlace();
            var address = place.formatted_address;
            var latitude = place.geometry.location.A;
            var longitude = place.geometry.location.F;
            var mesg = "Address: " + address;
            mesg += "\nLatitude: " + latitude;
            mesg += "\nLongitude: " + longitude;
            $('#latitude').val(latitude);
            $('#longitude').val(longitude);
          //  alert(mesg);
        });
    });
```

My in put feild name is "job_location"
 But in console i have error like this

```
       (index):586 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'event' of undefined
```

Please guide me.

Comment: Did you include the google maps library?

Comment: are you added jquery ui js in footer after jquery and jquery min js

Comment: @motanelu how can a add library

Comment: @MilanParekh i have written script in specific blade file where i have added all the script code. Please guide me in this regard

Comment: @Learner becuase this error only fire when your js not included or not in row how i said you..please check that first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to use google maps search in your input text feild

1. Generae Api Key for your web aplication
2. give id to your text feild like id="myAddress"
3. paste following code at the end of the blade.php where you have to acess the location

   ```
      <script>
       function initialize() {

        var input = document.getElementById('myAddress');
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
       }

   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
       </script>
   ```
4. Add these line in the layout file in mycase main.blade.php in  tag

   ```
       <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=Your key here &libraries=places"
           async defer></script>
       <script>
       function initMap(){}
       </script>
   ```
5. if you in include jQuery file in you main.blade.php' in the        @yield('page_scripts') please remove it. 
   Enjoy :)

Answer (score 1):

Please check google autocomplete working code:

```
      <label for="searchTextField">Please Insert an address:</label>
      <br>
      <input id="searchTextField" type="text" size="50">  

     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>

    <script>

      var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
var options = {
    componentRestrictions: {
        geocode:[]
    }
};

var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);

google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {

    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    var lat = place.geometry.location.lat();
    var long = place.geometry.location.lng();
    alert(lat + ", " + long);

});

 </script>
```

Here is working link for this:

http://jsfiddle.net/uxvMF/39/

Thanks